# "Put me in touch with whomever created it"?

Tags: grammatical-case, syntactic-analysis, relative-pronouns, whoever-vs-whomever

He created it.  Put me in touch with him.

So which is correct and why:

- Put me in touch with whomever created it.
- Put me in touch with whoever created it.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14182
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16024
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/44893
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56514
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84376
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110181
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/121043
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/121073
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/144792
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/145483
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/147747 and many more.

Comment: @tchrist Thanks for the references! These answer my question, and I am sorry to have annoyed you by asking a question that you and others have answered many times before. (But let me also add frankly that I think that your remarks to me are unnecessarily rude, and do not reflect well on this site, since you could have treated me more kindly.) Meanwhile, your first candidate duplicate was not the best candidate for a duplicate.

Comment: It is virtually always safe to use _who_. It is virtually never safe to use _whom_. _Whom_ is, if not dead, on massive life support. For photo evidence, [see here](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html). This is the short answer, and it suggests a strategy.

Comment: @JohnLawler That isn't really the kind of well-reasoned answer I'm looking for.

Comment: You want well-reasoned, learn syntax first. The actual rule is that _whom_ is required **only** when it is the object of a pied-piped preposition. See [Ross 1967](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/haj/Ross_1967.html) for details on pied-piping.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> - *Put me in touch with* ***whoever/whomever*** *created it.*

Your example involves a **fused relative construction.** In this construction, the antecedent and the relativized element are fused together instead of being expressed separately as in simpler constructions (2005 textbook *ASITEG*, page 191).

The pronoun **who(m)ever** is only used either as a relative pronoun in **fused relatives** or as an interrogative pronoun in the exceptional interrogative construction that functions as exhaustive conditional adjunct (*"I shan't be attending the meeting, [whoever takes over as chair]"*). -- *CGEL* page 429.

(Note: There is another issue that has potential to make things even more confusing, and that is when the fused relative is in a **"free choice"** construction. I'll address that issue near the bottom of this post. At first blush, your example doesn't seem to involve a "free choice" usage.)

In your example, as you have noticed, the relative pronoun "who(m)ever" has to fulfill two different case requirements. The matrix clause requires the relative pronoun to be in **accusative case:**

- *Put me in touch with* ***him***.

while the relative clause requires the pronoun to be in **nominative case:**

- *Put me in touch with the person* [***who*** *created it*].

In general, there are the three possibilities:

- If both case requirements are for a nominative, then there's no problem: the relative pronoun would then be the nominative "whoever".
- If both case requirements are for an accusative, then supposedly there's no problem: the relative pronoun would then be the accusative "whomever". But that would seem to be somewhat formal in style.
- If both case requirements conflict with each other (like they do in your example), then there is a problem: usually, the relative pronoun chosen would be the nominative "whoever". But many wouldn't find that fully acceptable, especially not in a formal style. (This is consistent with the general rule-of-thumb: *Use "who" or "whoever" unless it sounds off to your ear.*)

ASIDE: You will see some "grammar sources" (e.g. grammar usage manuals, "pop grammarians", grammar sites on the internet, retired teachers who wrote a grammar book, etc.) that, more or less, have the "rule" that the relative pronoun takes the case that is required by the relative clause. But obviously that "rule" isn't so good. For instance, "Whomever he marries will have to be very tolerant" (same as [18.iii] in *CGEL*) doesn't sound too smooth and *is at best very questionable.* And there are some sources that have a hybrid "rule", but the basis of their "rule" is that the relative clause usually decides on the pronoun's case. I'm telling you all this just so you'll know.

Back on topic.

Here's some related info from a vetted grammar source, the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL). On pages 1073-4:

> Case
>
> The pronoun *what* in [17] -- [F.E.: *17. what(i) she wrote __(i)*] -- is simultaneously head of the whole NP and object (in prenuclear position) in the relative clause. In constructions with personal *who/whom* and *whoever/whomever*, the pronoun has to satisfy the case requirements of both the relative clause and the matrix clause in which the whole NP is functioning. Compare:
>
> [18]
>
> - i. [*Whoever* is responsible for the damage] must pay for it.
> - ii. He will criticise [*whomever* she brings home].
> - iii. (?) [*Whomever* he marries] will have to be very tolerant.
> - iv. (?) She lunches with [*whomever* is going her way after morning classes].
>
> In [i] both the whole NP (bracketed) and the relativised element (italicized--F.E.) are subject of their respective clauses: the nominative form matches both requirements.
>
> In [ii] both the whole NP and the relativised element are objects, and the accusative is fully acceptable though somewhat formal in style.
>
> In [iii-iv], however, there is a clash between the function of the whole NP and that of the relativised element -- respectively subject and object in [iii], object of a preposition and subject in [iv] -- and the result is at best very questionable. *Whoever* would be preferable in both, but many would regard it as less than fully acceptable in formal style.

.

Since your question is about the case of the relative pronoun "who(m)ever", you'll probably also need to be aware of the **"free choice" construction**. Here's some related info, from *CGEL* page 1075:

> The free choice construction (*You can do whatever/what you want*)
>
> [23]
>
> - i. *Invite [whoever/whomever/who/whom you like].*
> - ii. *Liz can go [wherever/where she wants].*
>
> In fused relatives like these, the referent of the (overt or understood) subject of the matrix clause is given the freedom to choose: in [i] it is for you to decide who you invite, and in [ii] it is for Liz to choose where she goes. We have used 'free choice' to label one sense of *any*, and constructions with *any* + integrated relative are very close in meaning to the above: compare *Invite anyone you like* and *Liz can go anywhere she wants* (but see Ch. 5, &7.14, fn 32 for a slight difference).
>
> There is no detectable difference in meaning between the *-ever* and simple forms in this construction, and since *who(m), which,* and *how* can hardly occur in other kinds of fused relative, it is plausible to see the *-ever* as here omissible by virtue of being redundant: the "any whatever" meaning is entailed by the free choice and does not have to be explicitly expressed in the relative word. The verb in this construction belongs to a small class consisting primarily of *choose, like, please, want, wish,* and is interpreted as if it had a clausal complement -- e.g. for [ii] "She can go wherever she wants to go." Note, then, that *Sack who you like* does not mean "Sack the pserson that you like", but "Sack whoever you care to sack". However, the distinctive syntactic property of the construction -- that of allowing certain simple forms which do not normally occur in fused relatives -- is generally restricted to the case where the clausal complement is merely implicit, so that we have *Invite who you want,* but hardly (?) *Invite who you want to invite.* Moreover, *please* does not in fact license clausal complements: *Go where you please,* but not, in Present-day English, (*) *He pleased to go to Paris.* And with *like* the meaning differs aspectually from that of a construction with an infinitival complement. *I like to take the biggest portion,* for example, implies repeated taking (cf. Ch. 14, &5.6.1), whereas *Take which you like* does not. There are also constraints on the matrix clause. For example, the fused relative must follow the matrix verb: *I'll invite who you like* but not (*) *Who you like I'll invite.* (fn 17)

.

There's more info in *CGEL* that's somewhat related to your topic of **fused relatives**, but perhaps this is enough for now.

University libraries should have a copy of *CGEL*, and probably also city libraries too. To get a good handle on today's standard English, both reference grammars will often come in handy: the 2002 reference grammar by Huddleston and Pullum et al., *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* (CGEL), and the older 1985 reference grammar by Quirk et al., *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language*.

Note that the "2005 textbook *ASITEG*" is the 2005 textbook by Huddleston and Pullum, *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar*.