# Whoever vs. whomever where the phrase seems to serve as both indirect object of main clause and subject of subordinate clause

Tags: syntactic-analysis, grammatical-case, whoever-vs-whomever

"Would you give my extra points to whoever needs them the most?"  Should   *whoever*  be *whomever*?  My "opponent" in this discussion is using grammatical terms that I find unique.

Comment: There is no indirect object. The object of the preposition *to*, which is not an indirect object, is not a word at all. It is the ***entire clause*** *whoever needs them most*. You have to analyse these looking at actual syntactic constituents, not just a word at a time. You have to look at structures. This question has been answered many times before on this site. Even as a real, actual indirect object the clause doesn’t change: “Please give whoever just called all my points.” That's because the clause needs a subject. There is no single word that is the object: it’s the entire clause.

Comment: Duplicate of: http://english.stackexchange.com/q/14182
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/16024
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/44893
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/56514
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/84376
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/110181
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/121043
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/121073
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/144792
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/145483
http://english.stackexchange.com/q/147747 and many more.